# Ruby chmod works, but not for one directory called "js/"

Tags: ruby, git, bash, chmod

I've been putting together a ruby script that delpoys a git repository on my webserver (running gitolite) with a post-recieve hook.

After checking out the files I try to `chmod` the directories first, and the files after like this:

```ruby
FileUtils.chmod_R(0755, Dir.glob("#{deploy_to_dir}/**/*/"))
FileUtils.chmod_R(0644, Dir.glob("#{deploy_to_dir}/**/*"))
```

The first command works for all directories but one: `js/`. It just dosn't set the `+x` to this directory – while at the same time setting the `+r`.

Here's what happens:

1. Before: `dr-------- js/`
2. Skript does `chmod 755` on `js/`
3. After: `drw-r--r-- js/`
4. Expected: `drwxr-xr-x js/`

Ich checked the arrtibutes with `lsattr`. It gives only `-----------------e- ./js/` which shows nothing special. Is there anything else that could be wrong?

Changing it in bash directly works fine. What does Ruby do to this single directory?

Comment: Where does `js/` lie in the directory structure?

Comment: The second chmod call will unset the x bits, and it looks like it's applying it to your js directory. Is this all the code? How does your script distinguish between dirs and files?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen The js/ is on the first level. So right in the `#{deploy_to_dir}`.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard It doesn't?! Maybe during glob building with **/*/? I'll check it tomorrow. However the second command dosn't undo the x-bit for all other Directories, wich is even more mysterious.

Comment: After some fiddeling I rewrote the script in bash. This lead to the same error again: `/js` did not want to accept `chmod +x`.
So I tried removing the folder. Then the same appeared for a new added folder, that worked before `en/`. Now I'll trigger the script in some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was the problem, that `js/` or `en/` were the first directories in the glob. => **Now it's a bash script** and it works.

```c
#!/bin/bash
# post-receive

# 1. Read STDIN (Format: "from_commit to_commit branch_name")
read from to branch 

if [[ $branch =~ master$ ]] ; then
    deploy_to_dir='/var/www/virtual/whnr/vectoflow'
    GIT_WORK_TREE="$deploy_to_dir" git checkout -f master
elif [[ $branch =~ development$ ]] ; then
    deploy_to_dir='/var/www/virtual/whnr/vectotest'
    GIT_WORK_TREE="$deploy_to_dir" git checkout -f development
else
    echo "Received branch $branch, not deploying."
    exit 0
fi

# 3. chmod +r whole deploy_to_dir
find $deploy_to_dir -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
echo  "DEPLOY: Changed Permissions on all directories 755"
find $deploy_to_dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
echo "DEPLOY: Changed Permissions on all files 644"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing the order:

```
FileUtils.chmod_R(0644, Dir.glob("#{deploy_to_dir}/**/*"))
FileUtils.chmod_R(0755, Dir.glob("#{deploy_to_dir}/**/*/"))
```

Otherwise all files and directories will be matched by 0644 `chmod` and undo your execute bit.

Comment: That wasn't the real problem. The globs worked just on files and directories. It worked fine for all other files.